# Q: Simple-Salesforce make a dynamic soql query

Tags: python, salesforce, simple-salesforce

Was trying to figure out a way to get simple salesforce to just give me all the field names in a list. I want to create soql query that pretty much does the same thing as a Select * does in sql.

for obj in objects:

```
fields = [x["name"] for x in sf[obj].describe()["fields"]]
```

thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you really need to select all fields? This is usually considered as a bad practice and can affect performance (and in the case of Salesforce, it can lead to the reaching limits).

Comment: Im wanting to select all the fields for each Sobject because we want to create a data lake with all the fields.

Answer (score 2):

A list of field names in an object can be achieved as follow:

```
def getObjectFields(obj):
    fields = getattr(sf,obj).describe()['fields']
    flist = [i['name'] for i in fields]
    return flist

getObjectFields('Contact')
```

Your query to get the effect of `SELECT *` would then look something like this:

```
sf.query_all('SELECT {} FROM Contact LIMIT 10'.format(','.join(getObjectFields('Contact'))))
```

---

**On a related note:**

In case it is helpful, a dictionary of label/name pairs can be achieved as follows:

```
def getObjectFieldsDict(obj):
    fields = getattr(sf,obj).describe()['fields']
    fdict = {}
    for i in fields:
        fdict[i['label']] = i['name']
    return fdict

getObjectFieldsDict('Contact')
```

I find this can be useful for figuring out the names of fields with labels that do not follow the standard format (i.e. "My Favorite Website" field label for "Favorite_Website__c" field name)

Comment: Jwok - your dict answer is very helpful. What if I wanted to create a dictionary with the name / datatype pair?

Comment: @gscott happy to help! To get a name/datatype pair, you would change `fdict[i['label']] = i['name']` line to `fdict[i['name']] = i['type']`. There are a large number of data for each field. By simply running `getattr(sf,obj).describe()['fields']`, you'll see a list of each data point for each field (e.g. `length`, `defaultValue`, `unique`). You likely won't need most of them, but you can find them as such if you ever need to.

Answer (score 0):

This method will return a query string with all fields for the object passed in.  Well all the fields the user has access to.

```
 public static string getFullObjectQuery(String sObjectName){
Schema.SObjectType convertType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjectName);
Map<String,Schema.sObjectField> fieldMap = convertType.getDescribe().Fields.getMap();
Set<String> fields = fieldMap.keySet();
String Query = 'SELECT ';
for(String field: fields){
  Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = fieldMap.get(field).getDescribe();
  if(dfr.isAccessible()){
    Query += field + ',';
  }
}
Query = query.SubString(0,Query.length() - 1);
Query += ' FROM ' + sObjectName;

return Query;
}
```

Comment: This looks like Apex code, I believe OP wants a Python code sample

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import os
import simple_salesforce

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--sandbox', action='store_true',
                    help='Use a sandbox')
parser.add_argument('sfobject', nargs='+', action='store',
                    help=('Salesforce object to query (e.g. Contact)'))
args = parser.parse_args()

sf = simple_salesforce.Salesforce(
    username       = os.getenv('USERNAME'),
    password       = os.getenv('PASSWORD'),
    security_token = os.getenv('SECURITY_TOKEN'),
    sandbox        = args.sandbox)

for sfobject in args.sfobject:
    print(sfobject)
    fields = [x['name'] for x in getattr(sf, sfobject).describe()['fields']]
    print(fields)
```